# ajax error not refreshing

Tags: ajax

My .jsp page partial code

```
function runAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.html",
        data: { testparam1,testparam2},
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("processdata").innerHTML="Success";
        },
        error: function(e){
            document.getElementById("processdata").innerHTML="Error";
        }
        });
}
```

In my controller that handles the post, i raise an error on purpose for testing. The client code shows the message 'Error'. With same session, i refresh my page and run it so that the error is not raised. INstead of "Success" I still see 'Error" even though i know the controller worked as expected.

should i be doing this

```
function runAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.html",
        data: { testparam1,testparam2},
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("processdata").innerHTML="Success";
        },
        error: function(request){
            document.getElementById("processdata").innerHTML="Error";
        }
        });
}
```

and then in the controller

```
try{
...
}catch(Exception e)
{
 response.getWriter().print("An error occured");
}
```

If in my original code the error is being cached, how do I clear it each time my controller is called?

Comment: Isn't the callback looking at the response code (200)?  You'd have to change the http header response.  Personally I would create a JSON packet and handle the response codes manually.  like {'status':0, 'message':'An error occured', 'data': 'yourpayload' }

Comment: @user1389596: Can you hook me up with any links? THis is my first dab at ajax/jquery. Appreciate it

Comment: The best link I know of is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Basically you can always return a string, and handle everything in your success() function (which parses that string).   The string can be JSON: http://json.org/, which can be parsed into an object with jquery.   The only time you'd need the error() callback to gracefully handle a server error (like 500).